# Change the color of entire tikzpicture

Tags: pgfplots

The default color in `pgfplots` is black. What is the best way to change the color of *all* elements to another color. I have used `\color` command to do so, but is this the best option?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
      \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} 

   \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \color{red}
        \begin{axis}[
           ylabel = $h$,
           xlabel = $t$]
           \addplot[domain=0:5] {5*(1-exp(-1*x)))};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the optional argument of `tikzpicture` and give the color name there. Other options can be set there as well, see the `dashed` option, but I don't think that will should be set globally.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[blue, dashed]
     \begin{axis}[
          ylabel = $h$,
          xlabel = $t$]
          \addplot[domain=0:5] {5*(1-exp(-1*x)))};
     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]